# I want to scale swf up to 100%, but at any percent down. Any ideas how to do that?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to allow the swf to scale when the browser window is resized, but I don't want it to increase over 100% (so it should only scale down).

This is an example of the kind of scaling the client wants:
http://www.voosfurniture.com/

But again, it should stop at 100% going up.

Comment: Actually that kind of scaling is really bad, you should use liquid design

Answer (score 1):

you can do it but you need to put your content in a container (variable "_container" below) :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        private var _initialeStageBounds : Point = new Point;
        private var _container : Sprite = new Sprite;

        public function Test()
        {
            _container.graphics.beginFill(0x556699);
            _container.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            addChild(_container);

            _initialeStageBounds.x = stage.stageWidth;
            _initialeStageBounds.y = stage.stageHeight;

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);
        }

        private function onStageResize(e:Event) : void
        {
            var ratio : Number = Math.min(1,
                                            stage.stageWidth / _initialeStageBounds.x,
                                            stage.stageHeight / _initialeStageBounds.y);
            _container.x = (stage.stageWidth - _container.width) / 2;
            _container.y = (stage.stageHeight - _container.height) / 2;
            _container.scaleX = ratio;
            _container.scaleY = ratio;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you _could_ forgo the container and write something convoluted to resize and reposition items on the display list, but this solution is probably easier. ;-)

Comment: You're right but by manipulating directly the display list, display objects moves, you will probably have chance to add side effect.

Comment: The client does not want to resize things properly, but using this method. So we must go with his wishes. :-)

Comment: So, my solution work or not ? with this code, content is not scaled over 100%